# bash 4.3 lastpipe bug or feature?

Tags: bash, pipeline

I try to use the lastpipe option in the bash and it seems to not work as expected when run from the interactive prompt command line.

```
phi@phiz:~$ shopt lastpipe
lastpipe        on

phi@phiz:~$ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.3.11(1)-release

phi@phiz:~$ echo yo | read a ; echo "a='$a'"
a=''
```

So I don't get anything in $a, yet if run in a sub process it kinda works though useless I need it in the top level interactive

```
phi@phiz:~$ (echo yo | read a ; echo "a='$a'")
a='yo'
```

Is this behavior expected? I did my RTFM duties and could not decide if this was intended or unexpected.

I am new to bash and this confusing when coming from other shells

Thanks in advance for any advices.

Answer (score 8):

Quoting from the documentation:

> ```
> 'lastpipe'
>      If set, and job control is not active, the shell runs the last
>      command of a pipeline not executed in the background in the
>      current shell environment.
> ```

In a normal interactive shell, job control is active, so the `lastpipe` option has no effect. In a subshell, job control is not active, so the `lastpipe` option does take effect.

Job control refers to things like the ability to suspend jobs with `^Z` and then resuming them with `fg`, so this is something you generally want. In your case, I might try to re-write instead to

```
a=$(echo yo); echo "a='$a'"
```

or if you really need only the first line of some other command, pipe it through `head -n1`.

If, on the other hand, you do decide that you don't need job control, you can disable it with `set +m` (as pointed out by @chepner), and optionally later re-enable it with `set -m`.

Comment: For completeness, you can also disable job control with `set +m`.

Comment: @chepner Sure, that's worth mentioning. Added a note, thanks.

Comment: Thanx, I thought I did all my RTFM duties, but surely I missed the job control point, mainly because job control was not my focus when trying to get this done :). The 1 liner echo|read is a streamline of my need that more ressemble something like cmd-that-produce-many-line | while read a b c ; do things with a b c in a state machine; done . And don't want to go up to awk/perl at this stage. Again thanx for the set +m :)